# Data modeling question

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, data-modeling

My clients use one of the following when they sign up for my application:

1. **Foo API** (requires a "**auth_key**", "**password**", "**email**")
2. **Acme API** (requires a "**secure_code**", "**username**", "**password**")
3. **Bar API** (requires a "**xyz_code**", "**pass_key**")

(fake names, and about 15 more omitted for simplicity)

I would prefer not to have 10-15 tables in my database just for the different API integration options I offer (particularly when they're all for the same thing and they just choose 1 from the whole list).

My solution was this:

Make a `api_configuration` table with a column called `api_name` which holds a code for a specific API (e.g. `"foo_api"`)

Make a table called `credentials_attribute` with a foreign key back to `api_configuration`, a column called `name`, and a column called `value`.

Then I build a UI for choosing an API. If they choose Acme API, it'll ask for a "secure_code", "username", and "password", and create a row in `credentials_attribute` for each of the name/value pairs.

On my ORM model for `api_configuration` I can make a method for looking up `credentials_attribute` values based on the current `api_name`.

Does this solution feel right, or is there another way you would do it, if you had to model a solution for this problem? Please explain your rationale as well (ie, better for performance, etc)

Comment: sounds okay, but could you not create a single table? Username/email is the same thing (well, you could represent it that way)?

Comment: @RPM1984 - I could. I just wanted some opinions on other ways (such as that which you mentioned). I'm partly leaning towards a non-flat version so that I have flexibility later for a client to use more than one API, but I left this out because I didn't want to bias people's answers based on something that isn't a problem for the time being.

Comment: The stackoverflow discussion below talks about pros and cons of different ORM approaches.  Even tho you're not asking specifically about ORM, many of the comments will still be applicable, since they compare single-table approaches vs. multi-table approaches.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413459/designing-sql-database-to-represent-oo-class-hierarchy/3427434#3427434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the case correctly, it looks like yet another case of the gen-spec design pattern.  Look up "generalization specialization relational modeling".

Tutorials on object modeling usually cover gen-spec, but tutorials on relational modeling often do not.  But it's well understood, and there are some excellent articles on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably prefer to do this with a single table itself

Have a single `UserAuthentication` table with columns like `IdentificationKey, AuthenticationCriteria1, AuthenticationCriteria2` and so on...

Number of `AuthenticationCriteriaX` columns = maximum number of criteria that any API will have. I am assuming it will be something reasonable like maybe 5 at the most but anything upto 15-20 is actually still is a pretty small table.

`UserAuthentication` table also has a `api_key` column which is a foreign key from an `MASTER_API` table which is the list of all supported API's

As for the UI part of the problem, i.e what label to show the user for any field from the `UserAuthentication` table, i think that is just a UI concern and as such you should just have the mapping specific to each api somewhere in your UI layer. The `api_key` column can be used for the translation as needed. The DB does not necessarily need to know those details, IMO.

Comment: Why do you recommend this flattened design over another? I'm trying to understand the different rationales that DBAs and software architects use when deciding these things.

Comment: I agree with @InSane - i'd rather have one table. Having 15 tables with the same end result is silly. Is it more flexible? Yes. But sometimes you need to weigh up flexibility with overengineering. You could always store the "main stuff" (those three fields) in a single table for all API's, then have a FK to a "meta-data-type" table, which can have extra stuff.

Comment: @orokusaki - my rationale for preferring a  single table is because logically - to me atleast - what you have is data used to do the same thing. - so having separate tables for it or even having a horizontal table is just unnecessarily complicating it. This kind of design allows me to just get one record for a user and gives all this authentication criteria to me in one go. Even from a growth perspective, if u make IdentificationKey + api_key as a combined key, you even easily tackle your future issue of supporting multiple api's for the same user as well.

Comment: @orokusaki - To summarize, the implementation is just simpler this way. Having multiple tables / horizontal table doesnt seem to provide any additional benefit over his approach so its doesnt seeem to be worth the additional effort

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all these properties in the different APIs are conceptually tuples of the same 3 thing, under different names, right?

Your description is from the DB point of view - I will describe what I would do on the domain side (which may be directly mappable to your schema).

I would create a single class, e.g. `UserLogin`, with the 3 properties mentioned above (e.g. `authenticationCode`, `userId`, `password`), and a mapping of API names/codes to GUI property names. When the user selects the preferred API, I can display fields with the appropriate names on the GUI, and fill the values to the corresponding properties of `UserLogin`. If needed, UserLogin can also store the preferred login API for that user. This way UserLogin is mapped to a single table on the DB side. I may use another table to configure the property names for each known API.

Comment: éter - no to the first question, I edited my question to be more explicit about the varying nature of each API's authentication parameters. Some have 2, 3, and one even has 4.

Comment: @orokusaki, is there a lowest common denominator for the API attributes (e.g. userid & password)? Can the extra fields easily be grouped/mapped to a few common attributes? If so, I would still try to go with a single class containing some mandatory and some optional fields. If not, this approach may become awkward and infeasible.

Comment: éter - -I'm just curious what the reasoning is behind recommending that. I can think of a few reasons, but I want to hear yours.

Comment: @orokusaki, I prefer working with objects of real classes instead of collections of name-value pairs, whenever I can. I am a lazy OO programmer, that's all :-)