# This should be simple. But how do I design this?

Tags: database-design

I have 2 kinds of business units; division and department. A business units has to be one or the other, but cannot be both.
So this is easy enough. Have a BusinessUnit table and a BusinessUnitType lookup table containing division and department.
However only divisions can contain teams. For each division there are one to many teams. Departments do not have teams.
So what should I be doing here? Maybe I should have a flag on the BusinessUnitType table called hasTeam?
Is that the best way to organise this data?
I am not sure if this particular design has a name.

Comment: Is this a homework? If it is, then tag it properly.

Comment: Sounds like a regular inheritance problem. Are you using an ORM?

Comment: Entity Framework v4. Yes I can see how the classes would be organised for this using inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Your case looks like an instance of the gen-spec design pattern.  Gen-spec is short for “generalization specialization”  ([see definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Generalization) ).   The gen-spec pattern is familiar to programmers who understand inheritance.  But implementing the gen-spec pattern in a relational schema can be a little tricky, and  database  design tutorials often skip over this topic.

This topic has come up before.  ([See sample discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879806/data-modeling-question/3880673#3880673)).

Fortunately,  there are some good articles on the web that explain just this subject  ([see sample article](http://www.javaguicodexample.com/erdrelationalmodelnotes1.html)).  And a Google search ([see sample search](http://www.google.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F3879806%2Fdata-modeling-question%2F3880673%233880673&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-ContextMenu&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7GWYE#hl=en&sugexp=gsisc&xhr=t&q=generalization+specialization+relational+modeling&cp=31&pf=p&sclient=psy&rls=com.microsoft:en-us%3AIE-ContextMenu&rlz=1I7GWYE&aq=0l&aqi=&aql=f&oq=Generalization+Specialiazation+&pbx=1&fp=e637dc619dfb9af3)) will yield lots more articles.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to answer without a broader context (for example- what technologies you're using, whether this is a new project, whether you have any other constraints on implementation etc.).
but generally speaking I would say:

1. If this is a new project, and you are not technology-constrainted, I'd recommend using an OR/M (I personally use nHibernate). You can easily configure it to fit your needs without worrying about the underlying DB.
2. otherwise- it seems that your original thought is a good idea. Depending on the DB you're using, you can probably create a constraint to enforce that logic, if you like (I personally would not recommend that, since it brings your business logic into your DB, where it doesn't belong).
   Hope this helps.