# shared table for entities teachers and students?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I have to create a database and I want to know what would be the best solution.

Let's say I have to store information about students and teachers.

Should I make one single table containing all the personal information (name,email,phone password) to both students and teachers?

For additional information should I keep them in separate tables as ADD_TEACHERS and ADD_STUDENTS?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to create a **people** table for the common data like name,email etc. You can then use a primary key column in this table, and if there has to be information specific to teacher (like course_instructor, head_teacher of class), then use that unique key from people as reference in your **course_information** table. Do the same for students too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your best route is to have a separate table for teachers and students.  You'll have what is called a one-to-many relationship between teachers and students: one teacher, many students.

But that only covers one semester.  When you consider other semesters, you have a many-to-many relationship between students and teachers.

In the end, you're best off with at least three tables: Teachers, Students, and teacher-to-student relationship.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is Map the entity relationships **(ER)** and its attributes.then design the database and apply the normalization strategies.

In the proposed scenario students and teachers are different entities . and find out thier relationship

- **ONE** student **ONE** TEACHER
- **MANY** Students HAVE **ONE** TEACHER
- **MANY** Students HAVE **MANY** TEACHERs

Then check out their attributes Example - **Student**(Name,Class,DOB)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are going to use the data.  If you have a lot of use cases where you are interested in "persons", regardless of role, or if you have a lot of persons who are both teachers and students,  you may want to learn the gen-spec design pattern, as it applies to relational tables.

[See previous discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001417/this-should-be-simple-but-how-do-i-design-this)